# pinch gesture in android web view

Tags: javascript, android, gesture, pinch

Is it possible to implement pinch gesture for android phones in web view?
I have an image and would like to scale it based on pinch. please suggest

Answer (score 0):

Refer Below Link. Might help you

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/1847

Answer (score 0):

http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.java

http://vivin.net/2011/12/04/implementing-pinch-zoom-and-pandrag-in-an-android-view-on-the-canvas/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which you are looking for: http://code.google.com/p/android-pinch/ . Using this example you can implement Pinch-zoom facility for views like imageviews, webviews and mapviews.